# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Prevent Direct URL Access to Document/File

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have bunch of files stored in a directory. Those files have links stored in the database like

https://localhost:44325/Repositories/Aopdio/2019/05/QWNjb3VX0FNT1NUSElSRF9LTA==.pdf

When I log in to my application, I am able to access the files via the application. However, when I copy this link and paste it in another browser, the file still opens.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I'd like the content to only be served from the application.

This is my startup.cs

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(RepositoryManager.GetBasePath(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPONE_REPOSITORY"))),
    RequestPath = RepositoryManager.GetRequestPath(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPONE_REPOSITORY"))
});
app.UseStaticFiles(
    new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "Resources")),
        RequestPath = "/Resources"
    }
);
```

This is the middleware that I have tried to implement:

In Startup.cs

```
app.UseRequestMiddleware();
```

The Middleware

```
public class RequestMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public RequestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, Func<Task> next)
    {
        var test = context;
    }
}
```

The extension that calls the middleware and is called in Startup.cs

```
public static class RequestMiddlewareExtension
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseRequestMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<RequestMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Func`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task]' while attempting to Invoke middleware 'App.ClassLibrary.Middleware.RequestMiddleware'.
```

Comment: Is the Repositories folder stored under wwwroot?

Comment: No, its stored in another folder outside of the solution.

Comment: I edited my question to include my startup.cs

Comment: What is the logic for the server to identify which request is from your application? You could implement your middleware before `app.UseStaticFiles` and check whether the request meets your request to access static file.

Comment: @TaoZhou I don't have any logic to identify which request is from my application. Should I have something like that? Are there any examples available?

Comment: I have added a middleware I have tried. Its not working though

Comment: First of all, I would not use static files if you need to add logic to retrieval. Include them in some other folder and return it from controller using `File(...)`. When you already have it in controller, have a look at AntiForgery - it should do the trick.

Comment: what do you mean don't use static files if i need to add logic to retrieve them? What is the best way to store files and view them in my application?

Answer (score 2):

In the default configuration of app.UseStaticFiles(), only files under wwwroot are served. If the files outside that directory is served directly, then either you have enabled static files for the whole app from your root folder or you have enabled directory browsing on the IIS. You can check and disable them.

[Update]
When you serve the files using UseStaticFiles(), the request doesn't method does not comes through the normal middleware pipeline. So you can't have the regular middleware features like Authenticate/Authorize. Either you can have a Repositories Controller that returns FileResult or you can have a custom middleware like [the one here](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/10/06/authorization-policies-and-middleware-in-asp-net-5.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I edited my question to include my startup.cs as well.

Comment: These lines seem to serve those static files:
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(RepositoryManager.GetBasePath(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPONE_REPOSITORY"))),
    RequestPath = RepositoryManager.GetRequestPath(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPONE_REPOSITORY"))
});

Comment: Yeah I need to serve them from there. Is there a way to ensure that the link can only be used when the user is in my application

Comment: Would it be better to serve it from the wwwroot instead of an outside folder?

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference

Comment: Sorry what did you mean by  the request doesn't method does not comes through the normal middleware pipeline

Comment: G.R. I have added an edit to my question showing my middleware but that doesn't seem to be working.